# Conditions for $P(X_1 + \cdots X_{n+1} = 0) < P(X_1 + \cdots X_n = 0) $ to hold for all $n$?

Tags: probability, convolution

Let $X_i$ be iid random discrete variables with pmf $f$ .

We may restrict ourselve to pmfs with finite even support: $f \in G_N$ ($ f[k] > 0 \implies |k| \le N$) or perhaps $f \in G^{+}_N$ ($ f[k] > 0 \iff |k| \le N$) .

I wonder if there is some characterization on $f$ (perhaps sufficient or necesary conditions) for this property to hold:

$$P(X_1 + \cdots X_{n+1} = 0)  < P(X_1 + \cdots X_n = 0)  \, \forall n\ge 1$$

Alternatively, letting $f^{(n)}$ denote the $n-$self convolution of $f$, the above is equivalent to $f^{(n+1)}[0]  < f^{(n)}[0]  $

In by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260920/tied-chess-matches-and-the-monotonicity-of-sum-k-0n-binom2nk-k-2n-2k) it's shown that $f \in G^{+}_1$ is not enough, but $g=f^{(2)}$ is.

Comment: One sufficient condition is that the support of $f$ is non-negative. In this case, the sum of the random variables being equal to zero is equivalent to them all being zero.   Then as long as $f$ does not only put positive probability on zero, the probability $P\left(X_1 + \cdots + X_{n} = 0\right) = f\left(0\right)^n$ is decreasing in $n$.

Comment: What does "but $g=f^{(2)}$ is" mean?